# Customizing shape of bounding rect

Tags: qt, bounding-box, qgraphicsitem

I am drawing a line using mouse clicks. The line is drawn using paint function as:

```
painter->drawLine(start_p, end_p);
```

The bounding rect of line is defined as:

```
QRectF Line::boundingRect() const
{
  // bounding rectangle for line
  return QRectF(start_p, end_p).normalized();
}
```

[image]

This shows the line painted. I get the bounding rect for this as shown:

[image]

I want to have the bounding rect according to the shape of the item, something like:[image]

How to achieve this?

**Edit**

While selecting any of the overlapping lines, the one with bounding rect on top is selected(see figure below). Even making use of `setZValue` won't work here. 
I want to implement this by minimizing the bounding rect to the shape of line.

[image]

Comment: This is a cross post. :)

Comment: Use [`QGraphicsItem::shape`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#shape).

Comment: I am a newbie. Can you please provide some demo code.

Comment: Did you check the docs I linked? There is an example there. Also check the docs for [`QPainterPath`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpainterpath.html). You might be able to create your shape with [`QPainterPath::addPolygon`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#addPolygon).

Comment: You cannot change the shape or orientation of the bounding box.  But you can change the shape used for collision and hit testing (as shown by @thuga) - is that what you meant?

Comment: @thuga Make your comment an answer, you may want to mention `QPainterPathStroker::createStroke(..)` if the user ever wants to create curvy lines.

Comment: For future reference: parts of the shape outside of the bounding rect are not interacted with.

Answer (score 10):

If you have an item that is not shaped like a rectangle, or is a rotated rectangle use [`QGraphicsItem::shape`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#shape).

This function should return a [`QPainterPath`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpainterpath.html). You should be able to create your path by using [`QPainterPath::addPolygon`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#addPolygon).

Here is a small example:

```
QPainterPath Item::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;
    QPolygon polygon;
    polygon << QPoint(0, 0);
    polygon << QPoint(5, 5);
    polygon << QPoint(width, height);
    polygon << QPoint(width - 5, height - 5);
    path.addPolygon(polygon);

    return path;
}
```

You of course should calculate your points inside the path in a different way, but you get the point. Now when you click on an item, it will only select it if the click happened inside the shape defined by the `QPainterPath`.

If you ever need to make curvy lines, you can use [`QPainterPathStroker::createStroke`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpainterpathstroker.html#createStroke) as suggested by cmannett85.

Answer (score 3):

There are two relevant functions in a QGraphicsItem that you should be interested in. The first is [boundingRect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect). This, as you probably realise is a rectangle which encompasses the whole item. Qt uses this for such things as quickly calculating how much of an item is visible and simple item collision.

That's great if you have rectangular items; you can just override [boundingRect()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect) in any items you inherit from QGraphicsItem or QGraphicsObject.

If you have a shape that isn't regular and you want to do things such as collision with an item's shape, then the[shape()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#shape) function needs overriding too in your class.

This returns a QPainterPath, so you can do something like this: -

```
QPainterPath Line::shape()
{
    QRectF rect(start_p, end_p).normalized();

    // increase the rect beyond the width of the line
    rect.adjust(-2, -2, 2, 2); 

    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRect(rect);

    return path;    // return the item's defined shape
}
```

Now, you can use a painter to draw the shape() item, instead of the boundingRect() and collision will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

`boundingRect` is always used for optimize painting process of of scene. So you have have no room  for manipulation here.

**BUT** if you want change area for mouse interaction there is [`shape` method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#shape). By default this method returns `QPainterPath` rectangle received from `boundingRect` method.
So just override this method and provide desired shape.

```
QPainterPath YourGraphicsItem::shape() const {
     static const qreal kClickTolerance = 10;

     QPointF vec = end_p-start_p;
     vec = vec*(kClickTolerance/qSqrt(QPointF::dotProduct(vec, vec)));
     QPointF orthogonal(vec.y(), -vec.x());

     QPainterPath result(start_p-vec+orthogonal);
     result.lineTo(start_p-vec-orthogonal);
     result.lineTo(end_p+vec-orthogonal);
     result.lineTo(end_p+vec+orthogonal);
     result.closeSubpath();

     return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must draw yourself bounding if you want some thing like this. let Qt have it's QRect for bounding and define your new QRect dependent to the corner of previous QRect, top-left and bottom-right. for example if the top-left corner is (2,2) your new QRect top-left is (1,2) and top-right is (2,1) and ....

Comment: "You must draw yourself bounding if you want some thing like this" This is not true at all.

Comment: it is simple to reduce my point and say (it is not true at all). if you can answer the question do. I create a whole project by QGraphicsView with all of these features. If you did not see this thing you can not say it is not true.

Comment: I can answer the question, but @thuga has provided the answer in a comment 45mins ago and the rep is his/hers to claim.  Your answer is wrong because you do not need to draw a bounds in order in set them, you can override `QGraphicsItem::boundingRect()`. Further more the bounding box is axis aligned so drawing a rotated rectangle will cause the actual bounding box to be much larger.