# Selection of lines through mouse click is not sharp in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview

[image]

In my view there are 3 lines. 1 Polyline, and 2 straight lines. I have named them as P1 and s1 and s2

> I am not able to select s1 line. If I try to select it , P1 gets
> selected ( though I have not clicked on P1 )
>
> Selection of p1 is also not sharp. If I clicked somewhere around P1 (
> not on P1 ) still P1 gets selected.

```
 void Widget::on_designButoon_clicked()
  {
      // For straight line S2
      QPolygon net0;
      net0 << QPoint(50,180);
      net0 << QPoint(600,180);
      MyPoly* _poly0 = new MyPoly();
      _poly0->DrawPolyline(net0,scene);
      scene->addItem(static_cast<QGraphicsPathItem*>(_poly0));
            // Same logic for Line S1 and P1
        }
```

MyPoly.h

```
class MyPoly : public QGraphicsPathItem
{
    //Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyPoly();
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
    void DrawPolyline(QPolygon polygon);
private:
 QPolygon polygon_;
};
```

MyPoly.cpp

```
MyPoly::MyPoly()
{}
void MyPoly::DrawPolyline(QPolygon polygon)
{
    this->polygon_ = polygon;
    QPainterPath pPath;
    pPath.addPolygon(polygon);
    this->setPen(QPen(QColor("blue"), 2));
    this->setPath(pPath);
    this->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
}

void MyPoly::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                             QWidget *widget)
{
    auto copied_option = *option;
    copied_option.state &= ~QStyle::State_Selected;
    auto selected = option->state & QStyle::State_Selected;
    QGraphicsPathItem::paint(painter, &copied_option, widget);
    if (selected) {
        painter->save();
        painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
        painter->setPen(QPen(option->palette.windowText(), 0, Qt::SolidLine));
        if(contains(currentCursorPos))
                 painter->drawPath(shape());
        painter->restore();
    }
}

bool MyPoly::contains(const QPointF &point) const
{
    for(int i=0;i < polygon_.count() - 1; i++)
    {
        QPointF firstPoint = polygon_.at(i);
        QPointF lastPoint = polygon_.at(i+1);

        if(firstPoint.x() == lastPoint.x())
        {
            qDebug()<<"Inside vertical line ";
            //It is a vertical line
            if(firstPoint.x() == point.x() &&
                    point.y() >= firstPoint.y() && point.y() <= lastPoint.y())
                return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // it is a horizontal line
            if(point.x() >= firstPoint.x() && point.x() <= lastPoint.x() &&
                    (firstPoint.y() - 3 <= point.y()) && (point.y() <= lastPoint.y() + 3 ))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the Qt source code it appears that `QGraphicsView` determines which `QGraphicsItem`(s) are located at the clicked-on point by calling their [contains()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#contains) method.

Assuming you haven't re-implemented `MyPoly::contains(const QPointF &) const` to do something more specific, that means that Qt is calling the default [QGraphicsItem::contains(const QPointF &) const](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#contains) method, which is implemented like this:

```
bool QGraphicsItem::contains(const QPointF &point) const
{
   return isClipped() ? clipPath().contains(point) : shape().contains(point);
}
```

... which in turn calls [QPainterPath::contains(const QPointF &) const](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#contains), which uses either the [Non-zero winding rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule) or the [Even-Odd rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule) (depending on the QPainterPath's [fillRule](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#setFillRule) setting) to determine if the point is in the path.  In either case it looks like the algorithm is designed to detect whether the point is in the interior of a polygon defined by the path and not just "directly on the line", so if you want a more accurate algorithm for your use-case, you'll probably want to override the `contains` method of your subclass and implement some more precise logic there.

Comment: Btw, I bet if you temporarily comment out the `painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush)` line from your `paint()` method, then Qt's on-mouse-click behavior will make more intuitive sense relative to what's drawn on the screen.

Comment: Sorry but I removed `painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush)` from `paint()` but it did not work. Problem is still there. But anyway I understood what you are trying to say.  I need to override `contains()` from `QGraphicsItem`. I will let you know once it is done. Thank you.

Comment: I was overriding `contains()` as per your suggestion but while reading I understood that, instead of `contains()` I should override `shape()`. So I tried but I could not. So I created a separate thread for it. Can you look into it  ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72407209/how-to-minimize-bounding-rect-in-qt

Comment: I don’t think overriding shape() can help, since shape() returns a QPainterPath, and the documentation for QPainterPath::contains() says:  Set operations on paths will treat the paths as areas. Non-closed paths will be treated as implicitly closed.

Comment: Sorry but it is quite difficult for me to override `contains()`. I am clueless about how to proceed. It would be great if you could help me.

Comment: You need to write code so that `contains()` returns true if the mouse-click location is on one of the lines, or false otherwise.  If the line you want to check against is horizontal, then test if the mouse-click's `y` location is equal to the line's `y` value (or perhaps within a few pixels of it, to allow for user-slop), and if the mouse-click's `x` location is between the line's two endpoint `x` values.  Checking against a vertical line is similar.  If you need to check against non-horizontal/non-vertical lines, there is a mathematical formula to do that, but you'll have to look it up.

Comment: While overriding `contains()` I observed following :  Addition sequence of lines into scene , matters a lot.  `If I (first) add P1 -> S1 -> (last) S2 -------- everything works perfectly` . `If I (first) add S2 -> S1 -> (last) P1 -------- S2 Can not be selected`.  `If I (first) add S1 -> S2 -> (last) P1 ---------- S1 can not be selected`   Why ? And how to tackle ?

Comment: I have overridden `contains()`. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Does contains() get called on all three items, or does Qt stop testing after one of the contains() calls returns true?  If the latter, then it’s probably a case of one of the shapes “blocking” another by having contains() return true when it shouldnt

Comment: yes. Here one of the shapes blocking others.  While selecting any of the overlapping lines, the one with bounding rect on top is selected.  How to solve this problem ?

Comment: I tried this link I override `shape()`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271623/customizing-shape-of-bounding-rect  But in the answer they have consider single line but I have `polygon`. So some option did not work.  For one of the option, it created bounding rect and showing it when I was clicking on line.. Why it is showing bounding rect  ? Means I am confused. Can you help me in overridding `shape()` ( If I need to override `shape()` )

Comment: I found the exact problem. I am creating polyline using QPolygonF. Internally , it makes it closed by connecting start point with end point.  Now in this closed area, if I click, it selectes only polyline P1.  How to tackle this issue ?  I have made another thread for this. Please look into it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72431179/qpolygonf-internally-drawing-a-closed-polygon-which-is-troubling-while-selecting

Comment: I'll say it again:  You need to write code so that contains() returns true if the mouse-click location is on one of the lines, or false otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I know. So I am trying over `contains()`. But in `contains()` I can not get all the 3 polygon.  Whose bounding region I am clicking, that polygon I am getting. Not all 3 polygon.  So If I click on P1's bounding region, then I get P1 polygon , and through line's logic which you had mentioned earlier I dont select that P1 because click is not on P1.  Till this perfect but I dont get remaining 2 polygon. That's the problem. How to tackle this ?

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: It worked ! Finally it is working. `contains()` was not getting called for all polygon so I simply iterated over every item from `scene`  and use `if(currentItem->contains(currentItem->mapFromScene(mousePoint))` and I got every polygon from `scene` and then logic in `contains()` did everything.  Actually I had a pressure to think differently and not to stick to only one solution but I believed in you and sticked to  `contains()` and I WON ! Thank you for your patience !