# change mouse interaction area in PySide and pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, pyside6

i need to change rect area that mouse active on it for item(mouse click, mouse move event, ....) to polygan. 
from this question [Customizing shape of bounding rect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271623/customizing-shape-of-bounding-rect)
we must change shape method.
but inside pg.PlotCurveItem instance (i need curve item), shape does not called !!
how we can change the area to for example to polygan?!

```
import PySide6
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg


class custom_curve(pg.PlotCurveItem):
    def shape(self):
        'not called '
        pass



plot = pg.plot()
line_item = custom_curve([0, 1], [1, 2])
line_item.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable)

plot.addItem(line_item)

pg.exec()
```

this is image of bounding rect that mouse active on it
[image]

and this is my desired area (only inside it active mouse event)[2[image: ]]

Comment: I don't see what the difference is between this question and the question you linked.